# why do I get a negative value in calculating a matrix with all positive number to the power of 1024?

Tags: numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am calculating a very simple 2*2 matrices A = ([[3,2],[1,4]]) to its power of 1024. I am using a numpy function np.linalg.matrix_power(A, 1024).  As you can see, there is no negative in this matrices, but Python return a value of negative number.

I have tried in different computers, but it still returns negative value.

```py
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[3,2],[1,4]])
A_1024 = np.linalg.matrix_power(A, 1024)
```

The result is

```
array([[-1201800533,  1891366230],
       [-1201800533,  1891366230]])
```

I expected value of all positive number, but why it returns negative values?

Comment: Wrap arounds, if a number gets to large, only the last 32 bits are used.

Comment: What @Willem said - you are trying to store a number FAR too large for the data type (int) so it is truncating the results (which every so often will seem to be negative, even if they shouldn't)

Comment: `A` is an array of integers (either 32 or 64 bit, depending on your platform).  Here's a simple 8 bit example of wrap-around: `np.array([10, 30, 61], dtype=np.int8)**2` returns `array([ 100, -124, -119], dtype=int8)`.  Change `A` to floating point and try again, e.g. `A = np.array([[3,2],[1,4]], dtype=np.float64)`.  But don't be surprised when you find that the results are all `inf`!

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: Trying `float64` is instructive but will also fail to produce the desired result.

Comment: @NPE, I edited my comment after submitting it.

Comment: @NPE: you can use `float128`, which manages to give an approximate result.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Oh wow, I didn't know `float128` was even a thing.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @NPE, FYI: the *actual* number of significant bits provided by `float128` is platform-dependent.

Comment: In case anyone else is interested, there's an ongoing debate around `float128`: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10288

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that in reality the values are positive. Numpy however here uses a 32-bit integer representation of these numbers (on 64-bit machines, likely a 64-bit number is used).

This thus means that the array can only contain numbers between *-2<sup>31</sup>* and *2<sup>31</sup>-1* as values. If you make calculations with larger numbers, then usually a wraparound will happen, the arithmetic will be performed, and the last 32-bit numbers will be re-interpreted as a signed 32-bit number.

We can use for example a 128-bit floating point number to get an approximation of the values:

```
>>> A = np.array([[3,2],[1,4]], dtype=np.float128)
>>> np.linalg.matrix_power(A, 1024)
array([[1.85422822e+715, 3.70845643e+715],
       [1.85422822e+715, 3.70845643e+715]], dtype=float128)
```

Here we see thus that the numbers are approximately 1.854×10<sup>715</sup> and 3.708×10<sup>715</sup>, these are gigantic numbers. A 32-bit number can only represent values up to 2'147'483'647, so that is far below the actual value.

For a 64-bit floating point number, this is even no longer representable, and thus infinity is used:

```
>>> A = np.array([[3,2],[1,4]], dtype=np.float64)
>>> np.linalg.matrix_power(A, 1024)
array([[inf, inf],
       [inf, inf]])
```